# Flask + Celery broker redis being overriden

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

```
class DevelopmentConfigLocalHost(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///tmp/temp.db'
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
```

This is pretty simple config.
As for my factory, I'm supplying app, and celery as global.

```
_celery
def create_app():
    global _celery
```

Suppling my global _celery with create_celery inside of create_app factory. Also made sure the config is working. It does.

```
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfigLocalHost())
    print(app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    CORS(app, resources={
        r'/document/*': {'origins': '*'},
        r'/*': {'origins': '*'},
    })
    celery = _celery = create_celery(app)
```

Here is my very basic create_celery factory straight from flask celery documentation.

```
def create_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )

    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
               return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery
```

If it matters. I'm running the redis server through wls. with redis 5.0.7 installed in the wls. For the venv, I'm using 3.5.3.
I'm using this command to run celery: celery -A flaskr._celery worker

```
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x21648d3ca00 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
```

As you can see amqp is being used instead redis.

```
 enter code hereconsumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//:
```

Comment: I've also printed the _celery.connection() right after _celery = create_celery(app). And the connection is correct

Answer (score 0):

Welp. Found an answer. I had to return celery from create_app(). I'm currently using **main** because for some reason py flaskr doesn't work with **init**. So the new command is celery -A flaskr.**main**.celery worker *very cumbersome* but I have to make do. Also regarding tasks, I can't do my usual structure of importing globals from **init**. instead have to declare them inside of create_celery or maybe I could just import from **main**